# How to stop script if user inputs certain characters - PYTHON

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in programming and I'm creating a roll the dice type of game. And I want to create a command in which if the user types in Exit, the whole script would print bye and stop. I tried something like:

```
commandLine = "Exit"

if commandLine == "Exit".
    print ("Bye!")
    quit()
```

But it doesn`t work at all. The script would go on.
This would be my script:

```
import random
from random import randint
import re


print ("Welcome to Roll the Dice")

roll = input("Do you want to Roll the Dice? \n Yes / No \n")

if roll == "Yes".lower():
    print("Nice , let`s do it!")

elif roll == "No".lower():
    print("Too bad! :( See you later!")
    quit()

dice = input("Press 'x' to roll the dice!\n")


if dice == "X".lower():
print(random.randint(1,9))

again = input("Sweet ! Would you like to try again?\n")
while again == "Yes".lower():
    dice = input("Press 'x' to roll the dice!\n")

    if dice == "X".lower():
        print(random.randint(1, 9))

    if again == "No".lower():
        print("See you later!")
        quit()
```

Comment: In the last part of your program (inside the while loop), you never ask the user whether they want to play again or not. So if they enter "yes" then the value of again will always be "yes".

Comment: As an aside, you have your lower casing backwards. For instance,  `if dice == "X".lower():` - `"X".lower()` is just `"x"`. You should do `if dice.lower() == "x":`

Answer (score 1):

```
again = input("Sweet ! Would you like to try again?\n")

while again == "Yes".lower():
    dice = input("Press 'x' to roll the dice!\n")

    if dice == "X".lower():
        print(random.randint(1, 9))

    again = input("Sweet ! Would you like to try again?\n")

if again == "No".lower():
    print("See you later!")
    quit()
```

This should fix it!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
while again == "yes":
    dice = input("Press 'x' to roll the dice!\n")

    if dice == "x":
        print(random.randint(1, 9))

    if dice == "no":
        print("See you later!")
        quit()
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. "try" is not enough textual explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Blocking until to get a character to termination:

```py
import sys
sys.stdin.read(1)
```